# Scope within several functions Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to produce a variable with one function and use it in another function, and then pass it again to another function from the second function. I have tried placing the variable inside the parenthesis in a multitude of ways but i cannot seem to get the variable to alert in the final function. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/GFK6B/)

```
function randomNumber(randomstring) {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 16;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    //document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
     // alert(randomstring);
}

$("#btn").click( function() {
        randomNumber(); 
        //alert(randomstring);
        update();
});

function update() {
    alert(randomstring);
}
```

I have gone through several documents on Scope but i cannot see what i am not quite doing right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your aren't returning anthing from the first function here is one way to do it by taking randomString as global variable http://jsfiddle.net/venkatjp/GFK6B/2/. 
`return randomstring;` in first function and `randomstring = randomNumber(randomstring);` in click event.

Comment: Although other answers are great, this answer is exactly what i required. Thanks!

Comment: Unless it is unavoidable, you should not favor this method (for the record, it is very ugly) and go with what I suggested in my answer. If you don't like that, check other answers which at least do this in less ugly manner.

Answer (score 3):

A variable declared within a function, with `var` statement, is visible only within that function.

So, you can return the `randomString` and pass that around, like this

```
function randomNumber(randomstring) {
    ...
    ...
    return randomstring;
}

$("#btn").click( function() {
    update(randomNumber());
});

function update(randomstring) {
    alert(randomstring);
}
```

Comment: This is much better practice than solutions that recommend declaring `var randomstring` in the global namespace. Now your randomNumber() function can be used more than once as opposed to being a one-time-off function that can't be used for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare it in a scope that contains all the functions that use it.

```
var randomstring; // e.g. here

function randomNumber(randomstring) {
    randomstring = ''; // No var here. Use the existing one, not a new one in local scope
```

Answer (score 1):

define `var randomstring = '';` in `global` name space, not in `randomNumber` function

JS

```
var randomstring = '';
function randomNumber() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 16;
    randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
}

$("#btn").click( function() {
        randomNumber();
        update();
});

function update() {
    alert(randomstring);
}
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/GFK6B/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

The `randomstring` variable is with the randomNumber scope. So you have a few options on how to allow the update function to use it.

1. **Make it a Global Variable** - This is the worst solution.
2. **Rewrite the Update Function** - Call the update function with the randomString as a parameter like so:

   `function update(randomstring) {
      alert(randomstring);
    }`
3. **Create an Object** - Wrapping both functions in an object with randomstring being a property of said object. Here is an example:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFK6B/3/

```
var obj = {
    randomNumber: function() {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var string_length = 16;
        var randomstring = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
        }

        this.randomstring = randomstring
    },
    update: function() {
        alert(this.randomstring)
    }
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
    obj.randomNumber()
    obj.update()
})
```